# Invoke click only works with msgbox in between

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to automatically sync to my expedia account using my ical's from other websites

- If I remove the code `MsgBox("added")`, the `addtocallendar` click will not work.
- If i manually click the ok from the `MsgBox`, all the values get added each at its time to the calendar in the website , and this does not happen when I remove the `msgbox`. 
  Instead, what happens is that only the last values from the for cycle get added to the elements `startdate` and `endDate`, but the invoke click from `addtocalendarbutton` does nothing.

I tought this was a time problem, so i also tried to add `threading.thread.sleep(500)` in between.

But, the same thing happened and it took longer for the page to show up.

I even made a variable counting the amount of times `webbrowser1_documentCompleted_1` happened to know that the 3rd page was logged-in and the page where i wanted to apply the values to the inputs also happened the same thing (slowing only the screen that shows up in the 2nd `webbrowser1_documentCompleted_1` iteration)

I only seem to get this to properly add the values to the webpage when i manually click the msgbox, which takes out the purpose of what am doing that is trying to avoid overbookings and get the calendars to sync.

I can't quite grasp the concept of what happens when a msgbox shows that could interfere in all of this , so i could think of another solution.

Or even if there is anything that I could do diferent to have the same solution

Thanks in advance

```
    Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection
    Elems = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")

    If variavelinicial = 1 Then

        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("username").Item(0).SetAttribute("value", "balhblah")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password").Item(0).SetAttribute("value", "blahbblah")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0).InvokeMember ("click")

    End If

    On Error GoTo erro

    Dim data_hoje As Date = Today
    Dim data_hoje_formatada = data_hoje.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.ics")
    Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("C:\test.ics")
    Dim datas_end(lineCount.Length) As String
    Dim datas_start(lineCount.Length) As String

    If variavelinicial = 3 Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To lineCount.Length - 1

            If lineCount(i).Contains("DTEND") Then

                datas_end(x) = lineCount(i).Substring(lineCount(i).Length - 8)
                datas_start(x) = lineCount(i - 1).Substring(lineCount(i - 1).Length - 8)

                x = x + 1
                i = i + 2

                If data_hoje_formatada <= datas_start(x - 1) Then

                    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("startDate").SetAttribute("value", datas_start(x - 1).Substring(4, 2) + "/" + datas_start(x - 1).Substring(6) + "/" + datas_start(x - 1).Substring(0, 4))
                    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("endDate").SetAttribute("value", datas_end(x - 1).Substring(4, 2) + "/" + datas_end(x - 1).Substring(6) + "/" + datas_end(x - 1).Substring(0, 4))

                    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("endDate").InvokeMember ("focus")
                    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("endDate").InvokeMember ("click")

                    MsgBox ("added")

                    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("addToCalendarButton").InvokeMember ("focus")
                    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("addToCalendarButton").InvokeMember ("click")

                End If

            End If

        Next

    End If

erro:
    Err.Clear()
    Resume Next
```

Comment: One more thing so I don't confuse anyone , I also tried to run the code after the email and password was manually set , with the page fully loaded , and it only showed me the last values of the cycle as I described and not invoking any addtocalendar clicks , so , the code also doesn't work when the page is fully loaded and such , so  variavelinicial = 3 , that is the third page loaded after the program begins influences nothing on the error .

Comment: This is not VBA?  Or javascript.

Comment: @TimWilliams I would go for vb.net myself. Been a long time since I touched ASP so can't remember that syntax!